# How can i export my deep neural network model?

Tags: python

Every time I need to test, I need to execute the code from the beginning and I need to wait for training every time.
How can I export and use it on every image I send to it?
I used TensorFlow

Comment: First hit with google for "save tensorflow model": https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Comment: Please also provide code or screenshots of any attempts made: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can save it using

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

and then load it using

```
savedModel=tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
```

That allows you to skip the training part.